# What is the floating-point (__m256d) version of the non-temporal streaming load intrinsic (_mm256_stream_load_si256)?

Tags: c++, x86, simd, intrinsics, avx2

In AVX/AVX2 I could only find [`_mm256_stream_load_si256()`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=4653,525,3,4701,4695,4602,4601,97,3289,4601,4602,97,4601,1191,1197,1192,1194,4701,1170,5200,5152,5200,5159,5216,5223,4704,3406,4704,3045,4077,5216,5216,5213,5213&text=stream_lo) , which is for `__m256i`. Is there no way to stream-load `__m256d` and why? (I would like to load it without polluting CPU cache)

Is there any obstacle for doing the following (aggressive casting)?

```
__m256d *pDest = /* ... */;
__m256d *pSrc = /* ... */;

/* ... */

const __m256i iWeight = _mm256_stream_load_si256(reinterpret_cast<const __m256i*>(pSrc));
const __m256d prior = _mm256_div_pd(*reinterpret_cast<const __m256d*>(&iWeight), divisor);
_mm256_stream_pd(reinterpret_cast<double*>(pDest), prior);
```

Comment: What is difference between __m256d and __m256i?

Comment: @MarekVitek, `__m256d` contains 4 `double`s. `__m256i` contains unions for 32 `uint8_t`/`int8_t`, 16 `uint16_t`/`int16_t`, 8 `uint32_t`/`int32_t` and 4 `uint64_t`/`int64_t`. So they are both 32-byte long and occupy 1 YMM register.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `_mm256_stream_load_si256()` intrinsic corresponds to the [`(V)MOVNTDQA` instruction](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_194.html). This is the *only* non-temporal load instruction, so this is the one you *have* to use, even when you are loading floating-point data.

(The other three non-temporal instructions only do *stores*: [`(V)MOVNTDQ`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_194.html) ([`_mm256_stream_si256`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/683772)) is for double quadword integers, [`(V)MOVNTPS`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_197.html) ([`_mm256_stream_ps`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/683771)) is for packed single-precision floating-point values, and [`(V)MOVNTPD`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_196.html) ([`_mm256_stream_pd`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/683770)) is for packed double-precision floating-point values.)

The cast from `__m256i*` to `__m256d*`, and vice versa, is safe. These are just bits, and they're all stored in `YMM` registers. I've never seen a compiler that had trouble with these types of casts. Probably should check the resulting assembly code to be sure that it's not doing something funky, though!

The only time it would matter is on certain processors, where there is a domain-crossing penalty when you mix floating-point SIMD instructions with integer SIMD instructions. But since the only NT load is in the integer domain, you really have no choice here.

Note that *all* non-temporal instructions (loads and stores) require *aligned* addresses!